# Why is an app launcher icon scaled?

Tags: android, icons, resolution, miui

I created 5 standard png icons for my app. When I run an app on my Xiaomi Redmi 3S, launcher icon comes from xhdpi folder. So it should be in 96x96 resolution. But I see definitely that icon is blurred. It is scaled to 122x122. Other icons like Facebook, Messenger etc are very clear. What can I do, to make my launcher icon also clear? Can I put icon with higher resolution in xhdpi folder and it will be ok for Google Play app verification process?

My Xiaomi resolution is 720x1280 and it has MIUI 8.5.4 if it important.

Comment: Are You using mip-map folder for icons?

Comment: Yes, they are in mip-map folders.

Comment: So I have no idea maybe it's a specific to MIUI, I found this:
http://en.miui.com/thread-865923-1-1.html

Comment: Thanks. I found other topics with the same problem. No I'm just wondering how it is possible that other icons look quite good.

Comment: what i tend to do is make the image Larger than what its is supposed to be in the first instance. then when importing to android studio i import it through the import image asset option. then when it scales it to the sizes its not blurry